# OpenMPI: Broadcasting certain elements of an array

Tags: arrays, mpi, broadcast, openmpi

I need my processes to have a copy of the source array, then letting a process manipulate selectively some elements of the array, and then when everything finishes, I need to update the source array for ALL PROCESSES, by changing different elements of the array from different processes. It is mandatory that all processes possess the same array before manipulation starts. The following code may illustrate the problem:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int id, p, array[10];
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
    int k = id;
    while (k<10)
    {
        array[k]=k*(1+id);
        printf("%d %d %d \n",id,k,array[k]);
        MPI_Bcast(&array[k],1,MPI_INT,id,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        k += p ;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    if ( id == 0 )
    {
        for (k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", array[k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running with np 2, I expect the output to be something like 0, 2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 8, 18. But, while I am getting the id = 0 numbers right, the id = 1 numbers are not coming out as expected, and I believe it is an issue with the memory address not being the same for the two processes. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least part of your problem is caused by this statement

```
    MPI_Bcast(&array[k],1,MPI_INT,id,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

since `id` will have a different value on each process.

The whole concept of a broadcast is that one process sends value(s) to all other processes.  In the call to `MPI_Bcast` the fourth argument, `id` here, identifies the process that does the sending and that should be the same value on each process that participates in the broadcast.  You should probably change that to `0`.  Or possibly to  `k`.

Once you've broadcast the initial state of the array to all processes, then you can think about manipulating it on each process, and after that, about gathering the data back to the root process.  I think you are being too clever for your own good trying to accomplish all that in one loop with multiple calls to `MPI_Bcast`.

Comment: Okay, so I can send this from `id != 0` to `id == 0` first and then make `id == 0` broadcast the message?